# How does PowerShell handle large data sets?

Tags: powershell

Say that Get-ChildItem returns millions of items. How does PowerShell handle this? Can I process the data in batches? Will the command block the console until the data is retrieved?

I'm new to PowerShell so it would be great if someone could explain the basic principles of handling operations that return many items / can take long time to finish.

Answer (score 6):

Powershell cmdlets process data one record at a time. If you pipe the output of get-childitem to a script block or another cmdlet it should execute both in parallel. That is to say, your script block will execute as soon as a record is available, while get-childitem is still retrieving records. Of course, as it is a console app, the console will naturally be blocked until all records are processed, unless you prompt the user for more data during the processing of a record, or the user terminates the command. If you have time/resource intensive processing to do you may want to consider having your cmdlet use a background job (see [this msdn article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd878288%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).

Comment: Technically you can also process records as a batch, by having the ProcessRecord method accumulate records in your own data structure and then processing/generating output in the EndProcessing method. There aren't a many reasons to do this though, it's always better to process the records as a stream to avoid the additional memory requirements and to take advantage of the inherent parallelism.

Comment: That's a good answer - made me think of the Begin, Process and End statements within a cmdlet as well - i think they are worth mentioning as well. the begin will happen once, before the first record is processed, the process is repeated for each record and the end is the last thing to run. 
Not really that relevant to the question but worth knowing if you are going to be processing large amounts of data with a custom cmdlet. (apologies for any spelling errors!!)